# ggplot increase size of waffle chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, size, legend, waffle-chart

I have a waffle chart which looks like this:

[image]

using this code:

```
output$DS47<- renderPlot({
plot_tab6<-waffle(DS27$Prozent, rows=11)
  mydata <- c('Auslandsstudium'=57, 'Auslandspraktikum'=  30, 
              'Sprachkurs'=5, 'Studienreise'=11, 'Sonstige'=14 )
  plot_tab6 <- waffle(mydata, title = "lalalalal")
  return(plot_tab6)
})
```

however it is very small, especially the legend. How can I increase the size?

Comment: ( author here) It's `coord_fixed()` so you'll have to increase the size of the plot output area dimensions until you get to an acceptable display size.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this!

Answer (score 3):

I didn't know waffle returns an ggplot object. I solved the issue using this code:

```
output$DS47<- renderPlot({
  mydata <- c('Auslandsstudium'=57, 'Auslandspraktikum'=  30, 'Sprachkurs'=5, 'Studienreise'=11, 'Sonstige'=14 )
  plot_tab6 <- waffle(mydata) +
    ggtitle("lalalala ?")+
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5,size = 27, face = "bold", colour = "darkred"),
                              legend.text = element_text(size = 15))
  return(plot_tab6)
})
```